# Perform group aggregation to populate field values in RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have to write a code that at first step send a text file to one RDD, then based on VIN populate the null cells.

The CSV file is:

```
 '1,I,VXIO456XLBB630221,Nissan,Altima,2003,2002-05-08,Initial sales from TechMotors',
 '2,I,INU45KIOOPA343980,Mercedes,C300,2015,2014-01-01,Sold from EuroMotors',
 '3,A,VXIO456XLBB630221,,,,2014-07-02,Head on collision',
 '4,R,VXIO456XLBB630221,,,,2014-08-05,Repair transmission',
 '5,I,VOME254OOXW344325,Mercedes,E350,2015,2014-02-01,Sold from Carmax',
 '6,R,VOME254OOXW344325,,,,2015-02-06,Wheel alignment service',
 '7,R,VXIO456XLBB630221,,,,2015-01-01,Replace right head light',
 '8,I,EXOA00341AB123456,Mercedes,SL550,2016,2015-01-01,Sold from AceCars',
 '9,A,VOME254OOXW344325,,,,2015-10-01,Side collision',
 '10,R,VOME254OOXW344325,,,,2015-09-01,Changed tires',
 '11,R,EXOA00341AB123456,,,,2015-05-01,Repair engine',
 '12,A,EXOA00341AB123456,,,,2015-05-03,Vehicle rollover',
 '13,R,VOME254OOXW344325,,,,2015-09-01,Replace passenger side door',
 '14,I,UXIA769ABCC447906,Toyota,Camery,2017,2016-05-08,Initial sales from Carmax',
 '15,R,UXIA769ABCC447906,,,,2020-01-02,Initial sales from Carmax',
 '16,A,INU45KIOOPA343980,,,,2020-05-01,Side collision'
```

I have written:

```
def extract_vin_key_value(line):
    sr=line.split(',')
    return (sr[2]),(sr[3],sr[5]),
        
raw_rdd = sc.textFile('/FileStore/tables/data.csv')
vin_kv = raw_rdd.map(lambda x: extract_vin_key_value(x))
vin_kv.collect()
```

The result of fist part is as:

```
[('VXIO456XLBB630221', ('Nissan', '2003')),
 ('INU45KIOOPA343980', ('Mercedes', '2015')),
 ('VXIO456XLBB630221', ('', '')),
 ('VXIO456XLBB630221', ('', '')),
 ('VOME254OOXW344325', ('Mercedes', '2015')),
 ('VOME254OOXW344325', ('', '')),
 ('VXIO456XLBB630221', ('', '')),
 ('EXOA00341AB123456', ('Mercedes', '2016')),
 ('VOME254OOXW344325', ('', '')),
 ('VOME254OOXW344325', ('', '')),
 ('EXOA00341AB123456', ('', '')),
 ('EXOA00341AB123456', ('', '')),
 ('VOME254OOXW344325', ('', '')),
 ('UXIA769ABCC447906', ('Toyota', '2017')),
 ('UXIA769ABCC447906', ('', '')),
 ('INU45KIOOPA343980', ('', ''))]
```

Now, I have to populate the model and make based on VIN by developing a method as:

```
def populate_make(line):
    vin=line[0]
    ...
    ...

enhance_make = vin_kv.groupByKey().flatMap(lambda kv: populate_make(kv[1]))
enhance_make.collect()
```

I just receive following error message:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 11.0 failed
1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 20) (ip-10-172-237-160.us-west-
2.compute.internal executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'TypeError:
'ResultIterable' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I split the data in second function, I use the split method but I receive:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 13.0 failed
1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 25) (ip-10-172-237-160.us-west-
2.compute.internal executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 
'AttributeError: 'ResultIterable' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: It is not clear to me if you are asking how to write the `populate_make` function. in this case, what should it do?

Comment: Populte_make method must populate the make and model to null values based on the vin values, the input of the method is the second component  of the RDD, but once I want to split the each line in the second method, I receive the error message

Comment: ok but you are not showing the code that produces the error. Moreover, `kv[1]` is an iterable and not a string that you can split. Please edit the post with the expected output.

Comment: there is no more code, I received the error on this line:
vin=line[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`groupByKey` returns pairs of type `(Any, ResultIterable)`. In the [docstring](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/resultiterable.py) the reason is briefly explained as

> A special result iterable. This is used because the standard iterator can not be pickled

I have not got the meaning of this yet, but I will look into it. By the way, the solution is to convert `ResultIterable` to a list:

```
enhance_make = vin_kv.groupByKey().flatMap(lambda kv: populate_make(list(kv[1])))
```